# Move from Android Studio back to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I installed Android Studio and followed the export instructions laid out at d.android.com on how to move existing Android Applications over to Android Studio. I made the mistake of thinking that I would be able to use both editors for my projects. What would be the easiest way to move all of my projects and libraries back to eclipse? As of right now, my eclipse workspace comes up empty. Thanks

Comment: were you using any distributed revision control software? Check this, click right mouse button on your project in eclipse and try click (At the end of the context menu list) `restore from local...`

Comment: Did you try 'Create Android Project from existing code'?

Comment: I would say backup, but it is too late, maybe version control system, but probably you don't keep there configuration files. So for future reference if you want to do something fancy with project remember to make copy for safety ;)

Answer (score 4):

you can use both at the same time but you need to do some extra work by using version control (for example git). An example of how this might work:

You make an empty project in Git. You then clon your git project to local. In the local folder you create your new Android project. You then make a .gitignore where you ignore all eclipse related files/folders. Now you can publish your project to git. Then you clone your git project to a new folder, this is where you studio edition is going to go. You then make a new .gitignore in the new folder for the studio related files/folders.

Now you have version control and you can use both Eclipse and Studio.

Comment: Which files are eclipse specific and which are Android Specific? If I just delete the gradle files, should they work nicely with eclipse again?

Comment: @EGHDK I'm not completely sure as I've only worked with eclipse. In eclipse I normally only ignore the bin/ and gen/ folders. I believe Eclipse has the most important files stored in the workspace folder which you wont commit to git anyway =/ But maybe the .classpath, .project and the project.properties... The easiest way for you to find out would be to create a new eclipse project and a new Android Studio project and then look at the different content in the 2 project folders. Please post back your finding for other to benefit.